# Having trouble in nested IFs in excel with true or false values in each IF statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested

=IF(AND(A2<=20151231),(B2=0) 0, 15, IF(AND(A2>=20190101,B2>=2),15, 7.5))

This is what I entered in the function.

if A2 is less than 20151231 and B2 is equal to 0 the value will be 0.
if A2 is greater than 20190101 and B2 is equal to or greater than 2 the value will be 15.

the problem is that excel says that I entered too many arguments and when I try to derive it it says that there is something wrong with the function I entered.

Comment: If the first statement is false the value will be 15
If the second statement is false the value will be 7.5.

this is my first time in excel please help.

Comment: Try =IF(AND(A2<=20151231,B2=0), 0,IF(AND(A2>=20190101,B2>=2),15, 7.5))  but not sure exactly what you want, as you were closing too many brackets...

Comment: And the 7.5 in your formula?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
=IF(AND(A2<=20151231,B2=0),"0",IF(AND(A2>=20191010,B2>=2),15,""))
it seems your formula has too much close and open parenthesis. When using "and()" enclose all logic in one set of parenthesis.
Hope this helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Reymond's answer is correct, assuming that you want the result to be:

```
0   - if A2<=20151231 AND B2=0
15  - if A2>=20190101 AND B2>=2
7.5 - if neither of these cases are true.
```

If you are struggling to see what parameters you are passing to which function, I would suggest that you format your formulas so that they are easier to read:

```
=IF(
    AND(A2<=20151231, B2=0),
    0,  
    IF(
        AND(A2>=20190101,B2>=2),
        15, 
        7.5
    )
)
```

This makes it much easier to see what is going on and it can even be done in the excel formula bar if you wish (by using Alt+Enter):

[image]